# Can the set of all sigma-algebras over an arbitrary set be uncountable?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

In my reading material, in the proof for the claim that

> Let $\mathcal{L} \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ be a collection of subsets of $\Omega$. Then the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ which contains $\mathcal{L}$ exists and is unique

the existence step is performed by first considering the intersection over the elements of the set of all $\sigma$-algebras on $\Omega$, and then using the property of $\sigma$-algebras that the intersection over non-empty collection of $\sigma$-algebras is also a $\sigma$-algebra. However the proof that

> the intersection over non-empty collection of $\sigma$-algebras is also a $\sigma$-algebra

is itself proved by using the definition and inducing property of $\sigma$-algebras, that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $E_1,E_2,E_3,\dots \in \mathcal{F}$, then i.) $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E_n \in \mathcal{F}$, ii.) $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}E_n \in \mathcal{F}$.

In light of the fact that these two set operations are over a countably infinite index set, I would conclude that either necessary the set of all $\sigma$-algebras is countable, or there is a missing remark in my reading material. However, I can't say for sure whether I am missing some small technical detail. What is your thought on this?

Comment: The proof is perfectly correct; your conclusion about how it must be countably many sigma-algebras simply doesn't follow. $\mathcal F$ is perfectly well-defined, and verifying that it's a sigma-algebra is simple. The fact that it's the intersection of possibly uncountably many sigma-algebras doesn't change the validity of any of this

Comment: If that's not a good enough explanation you need to explain in detail exactly _why_ you would conclude what you say you would conclude; the words "I would conclude that..." are not a convincing proof of anything

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich My uncertainty about the countability/uncountability stems from the definition of $\sigma$-algebras, that any countable union/intersection of elements of a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. If it is so that this property can be extended to uncountable intersections, I have no issue with it. It is just that so far my reading material has not considered this, so I am curious.

Comment: @EpsilonAway You are mixing two things: The properties of a $\sigma$-algebra, defined for *elements* of it. For those only a countable intersection is defined (and cannot be extended to uncountable ones). But in the proof above they are talking about intersecting $\sigma$-algebras and *not* elements of $\sigma$-algebras. For those you are not restricted on countable intersections because all you need are the properties of (uncountable) intersections and NOT the properties for elements of a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: If $X$ is an infinite set then $S=\{\{\emptyset, Y, X\setminus Y,X\}: Y\subseteq X\}$ is an uncountable collection of $\sigma$-algebras, and $\cap S$ is the $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, X\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a comment "If it is so that this property can be extended to uncountable intersections..." I finally see the problem.

> > **Fact 1.** If $\mathcal F$ is a sigma algebra, $E_1,E_2,\dots\in\mathcal F$, and $E=\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j$ then $E\in\mathcal F$.

> > **Fact 2.** If $\Omega$ is a set, $S$ is any nonempty collection of sigma algebras on $\Omega$ and $\mathcal F=\bigcap_{A\in S}A$ then $\mathcal F$ is a sigma-algebra.

No, Fact 1 *cannot* be extended to uncountable intersections. This is not contradicted by Fact 2, because Fact 2 is not an extension of Fact 1! The two facts are talking about different things.